# Testing ServiceStack services with custom factory

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, servicestack

I have read excellent article [here](http://www.richardfawcett.net/2012/02/29/accessing-asp-net-session-from-servicestack/) about accessing ASP.NET session from ServiceStack.

It seems to work great, but I don't know how to make a "passing" UT (Nunit) for services which need direct acces to HttpContext, because Nunit does not use Web.config with my custom factory configuration, and cannot create my custom factory.

```
<httpHandlers>
<add path="api*" type="SomeNamespace.SessionHttpHandlerFactory" verb="*" />
</httpHandlers>
```

So, I have a null reference at HttpContext.Current

```
class SomeService : RestServiceBase<SomeDto>
{
    public override object OnGet(SomeDto request)
    {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            return something;

    }

    IRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried also to mock a session in this way, but still not works

```
        HttpWorkerRequest _wr = new SimpleWorkerRequest("/dummyWorkerRequest", @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dummy", "default.aspx", null, new StringWriter());
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(_wr);
        HttpSessionStateContainer sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(), new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true, HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect, SessionStateMode.InProc, false);
        SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(HttpContext.Current, sessionContainer);
```

How can I create my custom factory in UT?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Hi @Boryslaw, sorry I only just saw your comment on my blog with this question. I don't have a definite answer for you, but suggest you look at using a mocking framework such as MoQ to achieve this. You should be able to do something along the same lines as http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/06/15/mocking-indexer-setters-with-moq.aspx I would have thought.

Comment: A problem is not with mocking I believe - my own SessionHttpHandlerFactory can't be created in Unit Test application. So, it is only possible to call default ServiceStack factory